# array doesn't accept the index if it is string

Tags: go

Here is my sample, why the first code is working and the second don't???

*This code **is not** working*

```
func main() {
    type Country int
    const (
        Egypt Country = iota
        Germany
        UnitedStates
    )
    shortcuts := [...]string{Egypt: "EG", Germany: "GER", UnitedStates: "US"}
    fmt.Println("Please use one of these [ 'Egypt',  'Germany', 'UnitedStates']")
    entery := os.Args[1]
    fmt.Printf("The short cut of %v is %v\n", entery, shortcuts[entery])
}
```

*This code **is** working*

```
func main() {
    type Country int
    const (
        Egypt Country = iota
        Germany
        UnitedStates
    )
    shortcuts := [...]string{Egypt: "EG", Germany: "GER", UnitedStates: "US"}
    fmt.Println("Please use one of these [ 'Egypt',  'Germany', 'UnitedStates']")
    entery := os.Args[1]
    fmt.Printf("The short cut of %v is %v\n", entery, shortcuts[Egypt])

}
```

Comment: what is the meaning "Working" or "Not Working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an associated map, where the values associated to your keys in the map represent the index value of its equivalent in the array. For example,

```
shortcuts := [...]string{"", "EG","GER","US"}
shortcutMap := map[string]int{"" : 0, "Egypt": 1, "Germany": 2, "UnitedStates": 3}
```

That should allow you to call the shortcutMap like so:

```
shortcutMap["Egypt"]
```

and from there find the shortcut with:

```
shortcuts[shortcutMap["Egypt"]]
```

will return "EG"

This is not a great fix for your problem because it complicates adding and removing shortcuts to your list and maintaining key-value to index associations. But it seems like you want to keep the array of shortcuts. As someone has said already, arrays can only be indexed with integers; calling `array["string"]` will never work.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of answered the question in the title. os.Args[0/1/2...] returns a string.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Variables

Array index cannot be a string. Not in GoLang. Or any other language im aware of.

Comment: you are correct and this is understandable, however the entry should be reflected as the second code, but how can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by reflected? The only difference between the to bulk of codes is in the last print line. Where In the second code bulk you are accessing the array using the enum (i.e integer) explicitly ‘shortcuts[Egypt]’. The first bulk should not compile if im not mistaken.

Comment: I mean how can I fix it so the user can enter the value which then will be the enum (index) of the array?
Do I need to convert the user entry to be int?

Comment: Id suggest reading a bit on arg parsing and cli flags. https://gobyexample.com/command-line-flags, https://github.com/alexflint/go-arg, https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.rapid7.com/2016/08/04/build-a-simple-cli-tool-with-golang/amp/